# SQL query for extract the highest value at a given time range?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem on a sql query. I need to take the last 30 days and then remove only the 4 results with the "voting" value greater

db structure

```
Id |    time    | voting
1  | unix time  | 3
2  | unix time  | 2
3  | unix time  | 4
4  | unix time  | 1
5  | unix time  | 6
```

I would like to take me only the data of: 5-3-1-2

I have tried with

```
select a.* 
from table a 
inner join 
    ( select votingng, max(time) as latest from table group by voting) v 
        on a.time = v.latest 
        and a.voting = v.voting 
order by time desc limit
```

Comment: show your `articoli ` table structure

Comment: sorry I was wrong, the table is the one that I quoted in the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to get the top 4 voting results in the past 30 days. Does either of these give you what you want?

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM table a
 WHERE a.time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
 ORDER BY a.voting DESC
 LIMIT 4;
```

or

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM table a
 WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(a.time) ) <= 30 
 ORDER BY a.voting DESC
 LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: I have the dates as 1470058711 and the query that you gave me does not print anything to me...

Comment: You may need to make sure that you're comparing equivalent data types. Try casting a.time and the results of DATE_SUB to the same data type. You may need to do a little research on MySql date-time types and comparisons. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html  ,,, For example, you may want to use `DATEDIFF(CURR_DATE(),a.time) < 30` but will find that you need to convert a.time to a date to get it to work.

Comment: Made some changes to my answer @Xanger. Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select v.*
from voting v
where timestamp >= unix_timestamp(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)
order by voting desc
limit 4;
```

Comment: I have the dates as `1470058711` and the query that you gave me does not print anything to me...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
Select *
From
    Voting
Where
    time Between CURDATE() And DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
Order By voting Desc 
Limit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using teradata

```
SELECT * from table
qualify row_number () over(order by time desc)=1 ;
```

or

```
select * from 
(select table.*, row_number () over(order by time desc) as RANK from table)
where RANK=1
```